# microsoft word: copy without formatting

Tags: ms-word, copy-paste, formatting

When I copy a text from Microsoft Word and the text is a heading in the clipboard I see it included a paragraph number. Then in another application I must remove the number manually.
Can I copy just a text without any additional information?
(The same is with Chrome when you copy a URL it adds a http:// automatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub FormatFreeTextCopy()
    Dim ffText As DataObject
    Set ffText = New DataObject
    ffText.setText Selection.Text
    ffText.PutInClipboard
End Sub
```

Note: You would have to Reference to [Microsoft Forms Object Library](http://excel-macro.tutorialhorizon.com/vba-excel-reference-libraries-in-excel-workbook/)

Comment: Where I put that and how to use it? Can I assign a shortcut key for that?

Comment: You can put this in a `Module` or `ThisDocument` and you can then assign it to keyboard shortcut.

Comment: I get a compile error: User-defined type not defined

Comment: @Michael - You did the referencing to Microsoft Forms Object Library?

Comment: You are right - I referenced a wring dll. It is working now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**Method 1:-**

one way is right mouse click and use this paste special option

[image]

**Method 2:-**
assign a shortcut(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) for this operation (**Note: by default Ms word not set shortcut for it so we need to set it by own**)

- `File` > `Options` > `Customize Ribbon` > `Keyboard shortcuts: Customize.`
- on Left `Categories` List section, click on `All Commands`
- Under right `Commands` List, select for `PasteTextOnly`
- then Set the keyboard shortcut for `PasteTextOnly` as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

[image]

**Method 3 permanent/Default Settings**

use this option which will each time paste as plain text by default

[image]

Comment: This would be a better answer to a question in the Super User forum.

Answer (score 0):

There is a generic "paste plain text" [solution](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/10412-paste-plain-text-and-copycut/) using autohotkey open-source automation software:

```
^+v::                            ; Text–only paste from ClipBoard
   Clip0 = %ClipBoardAll%
   ClipBoard = %ClipBoard%       ; Convert to text
   Send ^v                       ; For best compatibility: SendPlay
   Sleep 50                      ; Don't change clipboard while it is pasted! (Sleep > 0)
   ClipBoard = %Clip0%           ; Restore original ClipBoard
   VarSetCapacity(Clip0, 0)      ; Free memory
Return
```

1. Save this code to `paste_plain_text.ahk` script
2. [Install autohotkey](https://autohotkey.com/download/)
3. Execute your script

It will paste plain text using `Ctrl+Shift+V` shortcut. You can put your script at Startup directory so it loads on Windows startup.